# How to click on row when TextInput is focused? (react-native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

If I click on any ListView item, TouchableOpacity work fine. But when TextInput focused - it doesn't work, you need to tap twice. First click on item will only remove focus from TextInput. How to make it work without removing focus (in one click). Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}` on the ListView

Comment: if someone is wondering, this problem occurs with ScrollView as well. And this solution works! Thanks @Maksim

Comment: Thanks sir, you just saved my day,
After spending 3 hour on the source code, this works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from Maksim.
With the latest releases of react-native, you should use

`keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'`

As `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}` is now deprecated.